# add field Migrations no working django OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, addition, one-to-one

I try to migrate a OneToOne model with the corresponding arguments `album = models.OneToOneField(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`but when I run makemigrations the add field does not appear in my terminal.

All other migrations are done except the one why ?

Thanks for your help

```
class Album(models.Model):
    reference = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.URLField()
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='albums', blank=True) 

class Booking(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    contacted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.OneToOneField(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Terminal show me

```
Migrations for 'store':
    store/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Album
    - Create model Artist
    - Create model Contact
    - Create model Booking
    - Add field artists to album
```

Comment: 1. The cause of the error would be that you already have some data in your database for  some bookings ( Booking Model ) , now you are adding new field to the model , you might need to give it a default value for other previous entered values of booking in the database.   2.  Try  deleting all the migrations and then rerunning the makemigrations command .   There does not seem to have any problem with your models  . 3. If this does not work , delete all the data in your database , if data is important store it somewhere, delete all your migrations, then try re running the migrations .

Comment: I just checked in my database I have no booking models. I can't delete the migrations either because the error occurs before when I just do makemigrations
as I don't see the add booking I don't do the migration. thx

Comment: Delete the migrations from the app migrations folder and don't delete the __init__.py . This will work . Don't do makemigrations before deleting the migrations . Delete the migrations first and then makemigrations .